# Woocommerce add after cart Hook not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook, cart

I'm trying to display a content after cart button but hook is not working.
I have another hooks working rightly in checkout page like admin_notices, woocommerce_api, thankyou... but I can't use a hook in product page. I'm writing a log to trace if hook is using the function but nothing is wrote, in addition I'm writing the template file checking if hook is called

Below my Class code:

```
class WC_MyGw_Gateway extends WC_Payment_Gateway
{
$this->settings['show_content_on_product_page'] = false; // true
....
   public function __construct()
   {
    add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_payment_gateways_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'process_admin_options' ) );
    add_action( 'admin_notices', array( $this, 'check_fields' ) );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', array( $this, 'add_content_afteraddtocartbutton'), 10, 0 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form',   array( $this, 'add_content_afteraddtocartform'), 10, 0 );

    ....
   }

   public function add_content_afteraddtocartform() {
    file_put_contents('/tmp/woocommerce.txt', "\n ".__METHOD__, FILE_APPEND);
    if ($this->show_content_on_product_page)
       echo '<div class="second_content">add_content_afteraddtocartform</div>';
   }

   public function add_content_afteraddtocartbutton() {
    file_put_contents('/tmp/woocommerce.txt', "\n ".__METHOD__, FILE_APPEND);
    if ($this->show_content_on_product_page)
    echo '<div class="second_content">add_content_afteraddtocartbutton here!</div>';
   }
```

Below my Template code:

```
<p> PRE woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button </p>
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>
<p> POST woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button </p>
```

```
<p> PRE woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form </p>
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form' ); ?>
<p> POST woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form </p>
```

[single-product img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxdPq.png)

Comment: WC_Payment_Gateway certailny doen't get call on Product page.... it's called in checkout page. Use your hooks outside of 'WC_MyGw_Gateway' class directly.

Comment: But I need to know if I have to show or not, this info is saved in the plugin settings

Comment: options value you can get outside of class too

Comment: I'm trying to use global vars but I can't get the setting value

Comment: I have solved using get_option command. Many Thanks Alice!!